# Correct nginx virtual host for wordpress that's installed on non-root directory?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Let's say my main domain is example.com. I install SSL on the domain and I can successfully access domain. My preferred version is using www, so all requests will be redirected to `https://www.example.com` .

This is I've done so far and it works well when accessing root domain.

```
    # redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    # SSL conf
    server {
      root /var/www/example.com;
      index index.html index.htm index.php;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

      listen 443 ssl spdy;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;

      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com/certificate/join-cert.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com/server-key/ssl.key;

      # Redirect non-www to www
      if ($host = 'example.com' ) {
         rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
      }

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
      }
    }
```

The trouble is that I install wordpress on different directory. Let's say `https://www.example.com/blog/` . But I cannot access any articles (`https://www.example.com/blog/artcle1/`). I use CloudFlare and it says "The page you are looking for cannot be found."

Please suggest me the correct virtual host.

Note: I know it's easy to install wordpress on root directory and change homepage from wordpress settings into `https://www.example.com/blog/` . I don't want do that because I have flash on my root domain. I will keep my wordpress on that directory.

Comment: Are you doing the rewrites for WordPress somewhere?

Comment: @Jacob Yes. I install wordpress not in `/var/www/example.com` but `/var/www/example.com/blog`

Comment: so rewrite your to your /blog ???

Comment: @ADM Yes, a kind of like that. `https://www.example.com/` works well, I, however, cannot open `https://www.example.com/blog/artcle1/`. I suspect there is something wrong in my virtual host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are making the non-www to `www` redirect in a too complicated way. You should do it like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com/certificate/join-cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com/server-key/ssl.key;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

And then the actual issue you are having, this configuration should fix it:

```
server {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com/certificate/join-cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com/server-key/ssl.key;

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

So, here we change the redirect to work on the `/blog` URI. Furthermore, you need to change Wordpress root URL setting to `https://www.example.com/blog`, otherwise Wordpress is unable to correctly identify the locations inside WP installation.